# Can I trust IFTTT with my data?

Tags: if-this-then-that

There are some [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/) recipes that require **a lot of trust**.

- [If its raining tomorrow, send me an email!](http://ifttt.com/recipes/12507) requires access to all your Gmail content.
- [Keeping all the images you upload to FB photos in one safe place](http://ifttt.com/recipes/9075) requires access to all your Dropbox files, simply for uploading stuff to it!

Frankly, IFTTT is too new and I'm afraid to give it such extensive permissions.

Are there some reassurances that can calm my mind?

Do IFTTT take proper precautions to prevent abuse/misuse/hacking?

Comment: How would we know? We've no idea how they've coded this stuff. All we have to go on is their public [privacy policy](http://ifttt.com/privacy).

Comment: @AlEverett - if I had asked the question about Google, there would be enough information "out there" to write a good answer. Now, ifttt is less than than Google, but perhaps *someone* knows *something* they can share about this (e.g. their core team is known to be privacy aware people, some blog post somewhere that investigated this issue, ... some piece of information)

Comment: Or perhaps an ifttt developer is reading this and would like to share some information about their processes. I sent them an email about this.